# Photoshop: exact transform via 3 point selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, plugin

I need to exactly align maps of the same area. Because they come from different sources, they need to be scaled / slightly rotated / skewed to match the features. I can do it manually, but my work could be sped up if there was a way to simply select 3 "source" points on one image (e.g. corners of some streets), then, on a second image, select the corresponding 3 "target" points, and have PS automatically transform the first image to align with the second. Is there a way or a tool (plugin, perhaps) to do this?

EDIT: sample "source" and "target" images:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an extension for Photoshop called "[Perspective Tools v2](https://gumroad.com/l/PT2)" (paid) that helps with different perspective-related challenges and here's how I'd this task using it. It's not a 1-click solution and will require 4 points, not 3, but I think it's accurate and faster than doing this manually.

Let's say I want to move "East 42nd St" sign to the place of "Madison Ave" effectively changing its perspective. First I create a path with 4 points, describing a part of the image that I want to extract:
[image]

There's a function on the extension called `De-perspective`, that'd unfold a 4-points path to a rectangle, creating a smart object:
[image]

Then I create another 4-points path, describing where I want to warp current layer to:
[image]

And use a `Warp` function on the panel, so my "East 42nd St" is warped to new position:
[image]

Comment: Its okay to give links as long as you are a ballantly clear of authorship and you are ontopic.

Comment: ah, I'll add it then, thank you

Comment: Thanks, I own Perspective Tools, I'll give it a try. One question: in your example, the path forms the outer edge of the region you're transforming. On my maps, the reference points (street corners) are not near the edges, but deeper "within" the map, but I still want to transform the whole map, i.e. I want to transform a region bigger than the reference path I'm drawing. Will it work like that?

Comment: Could you please add a pair of before-after images to your question? It'll be easier to understand and answer this way

Comment: I guess the questioner wants to insert a new piece to an existing raster image map. He wants to pick three points of the new piece and then three points of the existing map. The picking must allow free zoom and pan between the picks. Then he clicks button "Shift, scale and rotate to fit" . In math the basic problem is a group of linear equations - six unknowns, six equations. The questioner doesn't want to type any numbers, it must be visual! Graphics of course adds its own flavour, if one wants something smoother than nearest neighbour style resampling.

Comment: @Sergey Kritskiy I added sample images. What I'm referring to, is that in your example, the points of the path define the outer edges of the region you're transforming. In my case, the reference points (street corners) are NOT on the outer boundary, but deeper within the image (i.e. closer to its center). There are no convenient reference points on the edge, like the white outline rectangle in your case. Still, I want to apply the computed transform to the ENTIRE image, not just the region "contained" within (inside) the drawn path, as you've done in your example.

Comment: ah ok, so you want to transform the whole image based on the set points inside it?

Comment: @Sergey Kritskiy Yes, the whole image. The maps have different extents (they show differently sized areas around the city), so one map may show regions near the edge that are not visible on another map.